# Xcode and Swift. The width is calculated automatically, but on the iPhone Xr everything is fine and on the iPhone X it looks bad

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, height

In storyboard:

[image: in storyboard]

In the code, add another view. I lay new view inside the blue view and center it

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print(viewTest.frame.width)

    let newView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 380, height: 100))
    newView.backgroundColor = .red

    let x = viewTest.frame.width / 2 - newView.frame.width / 2
    let y = viewTest.frame.height / 2 - newView.frame.height / 2

    newView.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: newView.frame.width, height: newView.frame.height)

    viewTest.addSubview(newView)

}
```

Looks good on the iPhone Xr
[image: iPhone Xr]

On **iPhone X problem** view goes beyond
[image: iPhone X]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of different screen sizes , so replace

```
let newView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 380, height: 100))
```

with

```
let newView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:view.frame.width - 40.0, height: 100))
```

---

it's better to

```
newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    viewTest.addSubview(newView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        newView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo:viewTest.centerYAnchor),
        newView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo:viewTest.rightAnchor,constant:-10),
        newView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewTest.leftAnchor,constant:10), 
        newView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:100)
    ])
```

To correct access frames of a view it should b e inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews` not `viewDidLoad`

Comment: I tried, it did not help
The width of the new view has become larger but it is not centered on the iPhone X

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(viewTest.frame.width)
    let newView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: viewTest.frame.width-20, height: viewTest.frame.height-20))
    newView.backgroundColor = .red
    viewTest.addSubview(newView)

}
```

Comment: `viewTest.frame.width` won't be correct inside `viewDidLoad` only for the device used in IB

Comment: I don't think this would create an issue.

Comment: What is "the device used in IB"

Comment: IB == InterfaceBuilder, e.g. storyboard or xib files.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, only this worked for me:

```
newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
viewTest.addSubview(newView)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    newView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo:viewTest.centerYAnchor),
    newView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo:viewTest.rightAnchor,constant:-10),
    newView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewTest.leftAnchor,constant:10), 
    newView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:100)
])
```

other options do not work
no matter what I do it in viewDidLayoutSubviews or viewDidLoad
view.width is the same for iPhone X and iPhone Xr, but the screen width is different